# Can I be forced to reuse an address by confirming a transaction that is part of a double-spend attempt?

Tags: security, address-reuse, double-spending

Imagine somebody injects two transactions *d1* and *d2* into the network that together represent a double-spend attempt. Having only incomplete information of all latest transactions in the network, I see one of them first, let's say *d1*, and confirm it with my transaction *t* that spends the funds at my address *a*. The network eventually resolves the double-spend by dismissing one of *d1* and *d2*. So, if I am unlucky, *d1* is dismissed and in consequence my transaction *t* becomes invalid.

I am forced to create a transaction *t'* spending funds from the same address as *t*, namely *a*. However, I'm not supposed to do that because it compromises my private key for *a* (see also [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/245/607)). If my second attempt fails again for whatever reason (maybe an attacker is flooding the network with double-spends to make such situations likely, see also [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/569/607) I asked), an even larger part of my private key is revealed.

Is this an issue and what can I do about it as a user?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/590/607) to another question, I can just reattach my transaction again without signing it, so the answer is no. I cannot be forced to reuse my address for spending this way.